# Is Tensor Flow compatible with Julia 0.6.4?

Tags: tensorflow, julia

So I have a project in my machine learning class and we are using Julia as our programming language. We can use any packages we want to build neural networks but I can't seem to get Tensor Flow to test correctly. `Pkg.add("TensorFlow")` works seemingly fine but here is the output for `Pkg.test("TensorFlow")`

```
julia> Pkg.test("TensorFlow")
INFO: Testing TensorFlow
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: could not load library "C:\Users\Ryan .LAPTOP-                
KJUJGIC7\.julia\v0.6\TensorFlow\src\..\deps\usr\bin\libtensorflow"
The specified module could not be found.

Stacktrace:
 [1] dlopen(::String, ::UInt32) at .\libdl.jl:97
 [2] TensorFlow.Graph() at C:\Users\Ryan .LAPTOP-   KJUJGIC7\.julia\v0.6\TensorFlow\src\core.jl:21
 [3] include_from_node1(::String) at .\loading.jl:576
 [4] include(::String) at .\sysimg.jl:14
 [5] include_from_node1(::String) at .\loading.jl:576
 [6] include(::String) at .\sysimg.jl:14
 [7] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:305
 [8] _start() at .\client.jl:371
while loading C:\Users\Ryan .LAPTOP-KJUJGIC7\.julia\v0.6\TensorFlow\test\..\examples\logistic.jl, in expression     starting on line 22
while loading C:\Users\Ryan .LAPTOP-KJUJGIC7\.julia\v0.6\TensorFlow\test\runtests.jl, in expression starting on line 6
=================================================[ ERROR: TensorFlow ]==================================================

failed process: Process(`'C:\Users\Ryan .LAPTOP-KJUJGIC7\AppData\Local\Julia-0.6.4\bin\julia.exe' -Cgeneric '-JC:\Users\Ryan .LAPTOP-KJUJGIC7\AppData\Local\Julia-0.6.4\lib\julia\sys.dll' --compile=yes --depwarn=yes --check-bounds=yes --code-coverage=none --color=yes --compilecache=yes 'C:\Users\Ryan .LAPTOP-KJUJGIC7\.julia\v0.6\TensorFlow\test\runtests.jl'`, ProcessExited(1)) [1]

========================================================================================================================
ERROR: TensorFlow had test errors
```

I'm running Julia Version 0.6.4 on Windows 10; if there's a way to resolve this error or a workaround I'd love some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TensorFlow.jl` does not support Windows.
You have two options:

(1) Try using TensorFlow via `PyCall.jl`:

```
using Conda
Conda.runconda("install -c conda-forge tensorflow")
```

(2) Use `Flux.jl` instead